# Inputs from a user for matrix operations in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, 2d

This is my code to add 2 matrices in Python using list comprehensions:

```
row, col = map(int, input().split())

mat1 = [[list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(row)] for j in range(col)]
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        print(mat1[i][j], end=" ")
    print()

print("\n")

mat2 = [[list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(row)] for j in range(col)]
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        print(mat2[i][j], end=" ")
    print()

print("\n")

result = [[0 for i in range(col)] for j in range(row)]
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        result[i][j] = mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j]

print("\n")

for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        print(result[i][j], end = " ")
    print()
```

I am able to run this code without taking the inputs in the above form but I have coding challenge in college and they are giving the inputs in the form of:

```
2 3
5 -1 3
19 8 4
4 5 -6
1 -2 12
```

I am having trouble taking the inputs and putting them into the matrix.

Comment: you don't need to use the second `for loop` for `column`, you only need `row` for loop.Bcs if your getting an input like `3 4 6` then you split the the data you will end up with first row.so remove the second for loop and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the second for loop.

```
 mat1 = [list(map(int, input().split(' '))) for i in range(row) ]
```

**input**

```
 2 6 9
-1 5 10
```

**output**

```
print(mat1)

 [[2, 6, 9], [-1, 5, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of input stream as the continuous string divided in lines using `\n` symbol.
For fast passing of txt file as input to your program you can do the next thing in cmd console/unix terminal:

In Linux/Windows:

`python code.py < input.txt`

Here you have your code in `code.py` and your proposed input in `input.txt` file with `\n` at the end of the file.